# Error handling response: TypeError: a.replace is not a function 'With a catch'

Tags: javascript, google-console-developer

I'm getting this error message without any script codes myself, and was wondering how I could find what is causing the issue. How can I find which extension it is, I'm dumb enough to find where I can see where all my extensions are. Just very busy learning a new language and applying it to a very important job

I've checked my code and saw it in many CLI projects, even when i just code html, and now when I code in vanilla javascript and python. This happens with or with any code written, I don't even have to use a.replace(I've never used it and it shows every time I put some code in).

```
Error handling response: TypeError: a.replace is not a function
    at hostname (chrome-extension://ocdjppogihmiaookphgljdbcjemckmjl/content_script/inject.js:1:1663)
    at chrome-extension://ocdjppogihmiaookphgljdbcjemckmjl/content_script/inject.js:1:2950
```

If you can tell me where to find all my chrome extensions so I can hunker down and figure out which one cool. 
Now if you know how I can find which one is the source of the problem, I'd buy you dinner and give you a big hug (^:;

Comment: Hello, did you tried read this https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en-GB

Comment:  That will help you find the extensions and afaik disabling them all and enable them one after another is the only way to find out which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is how to find your chrome extensions, you can do this by clicking the three vertical dots underneath of the browser's "X" in the top right corner, in the drop down menu click settings, then in the window it brings up look on the left and there will be a list that has "extensions" in it. Click that, then in the window it brings up it would probably be helpful for you to turn on Developer mode which is a switch in the top right corner of the page.

Hope this helps